# Dynamically setting permalink structure in Wordpress database creates 404

Tags: php, database, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

It seems like others have experienced similar issues as me in the past on this subject, but nobody has provided a complete answer.

I'm attempting to run a PHP script to update the permalink structure in the `wp_options` table for a slew of Wordpress blogs. I want to connect to each database and update the permalinks without having to log in to each blog and update the setting through the UI.

I'm successful at connecting to the DB and updating the `permalink_structure` field with the proper codes, but it causes a 404 when attempting to view any posts.

Is Wordpress updating other tables/fields to fully enable the permalink?? I'm having a hard time finding the complete answer to this.

**BTW:** If there are edits being made to the `.htaccess` when this is done through the Wordpress UI, I'm not seeing it. The htaccess looks unchanged when I do this through the UI.

Thanks!

Comment: Why was this voted down? I DID research this (including many questions on stackoverflow) and had a hard time finding anyone who had this exact issue and solved it.

Comment: Post the contents of your .htaccess.  Does this work if you change it through the UI?

Comment: Yes, it works just like it's supposed to if changing it through the Wordpress UI. All I'm doing differently is connecting to the blog's db and updating the `permalink_structure` field in the `wp_options` table with the appropriate permalink code, copied directly from the Wordpress example. When I do this, it causes a 404 on the post. Obviously, there must be another setting somewhere that's getting changed by Wordpress when changing permalinks through the UI, which is what I'm having a hard time figuring out. I've looked through their codex already.

Comment: Can you update the field in the database and replace your .htaccess file?  That might do it.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert - The .htaccess doesn't appear to be altered when doing this through the UI. It looks exactly the same. Is it getting changed somewhere else?

Comment: The UI will definitely alter .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHerbert, I think you've led me to a solution. I'll update with an answer after I try some things out.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress permalink rewrite_rules are kinda troublesome. They are great if you wanna do basic stuff, but it's damn hard to do some complex rules with it.

What exact structure you wanna use?

Remember that htaccess created by Wordpress just redirects everything to index.php, which loads Wordpress system (wp_load()), and one of its components parses REQUEST_URI.

First it tries to to bind REQUEST_URI into one of its regexes, which makes it understand what kind of resource is being requested (category, tag, page, post, etc), then it tries to find which resource it is (if it's a post, find which post by it's slug).

Comment: Let's say I have a pristine blog using the default linking structure, such as `http://www.domain.com/?p=123`. If I change this in the UI to use the "post name" link structure, the `permalink_structure` field in the `wp_options` table gets changed to `/%postname%/`. However, if I bypass the UI and update this field manually through an external database connection with `/%postname%/`, I get a 404 for the post. I'm simply trying to figure out what other settings are changed when using the UI, as it is not evident that the `.htaccess` gets changed at all.

Comment: I know this is old, but it doesn't provide an answer. It should have been a comment.

10 years later, and people like me are still trying to figure out how to programmatically update the permalinks structure without having to manually go into Settings->Permalinks->Save.